# How to get the date 7 days back from (new Date()).zeroTime()?

Tags: javascript, date

I am using (new Date()).zeroTime() to get the current date, how can I get the date 7 days back. for example, if today is 24th May 2012 how can I get 17th May 2012

Comment: What language is this, Javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C#, you can use `DateTime.AddDays` and use `-7` as your parameter.

Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx)

In JavaScript it's:

```
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() - 7);
```